# Disable MacBook Pro from booting into OS X Installer

Tags: macos, mac, boot

I've had problems with MacBook Pro some time ago - screen went black screen (probably GPU problems as [there](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/01/17/2011-macbook-pro-gpu-glitches/) [are](http://9to5mac.com/2014/10/28/apple-class-action-lawsuit-2011-macbook-pro-gpu-graphics-issues/) [lots](http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/01/16/owners-of-late-2011-macbook-pros-report-critical-gpu-failures-system-crashes) of complains on the internet fitting my problem) and after that I couldn't boot with *any* mode at all except for Single-User Mode (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). I would get either grey or blue screens.

Specs: 
MacBook Pro 15" Early 2011, i7 2Ghz, AMD Radeon 6490M, Mountain Lion OS X

The only solution that helped me to boot again was [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120507/boot-hangs-on-grey-screen-even-when-booting-from-usb-drive-with-fresh-os-x-inst):

```
/sbin/fsck -fy /
/sbin/mount -uw /
mkdir /Disabled_System_Library_Extensions
cd /Disabled_System_Library_Extensions
mv /System/Library/Extensions/ATI* .
mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMD* .
touch /System/Library/Extensions
exit
```

After that I've tried to install Yosemite OS X - thought that maybe clean install will help. I've gone with the installer I've downloaded from App Store, started it, laptop rebooted after a while (which is normal for OS X installation), then went grey screen again and nothing happened after that.

Now I'm trying to start with Single-User mode but it goes directly into Installer partition.

Booting with <kbd>Alt/Opt</kbd> doesn't help - I can only see OSXInstaller partition and Recovery disk (which goes blue screen if I select it).

**Is there a way to force MacBook Pro boot into your installed OS X avoiding Installer?**

Answer (score 1):

happen to me with yosemite installer, luckily i was able to boot with alt/option key and use lion installer dvd to repair disk and permissions and simply rebooted back in to maverick.